# Root Login Message

Tags: login, root

Does anybody have a idea how to do The following on Linux?

`$ ssh root@<HOST>
Please login as the user "ec2-user" rather than the user "root".`

Not only disable the root login, but show an message when login with the root user and then terminate the ssh connection?

Thank you.

Comment: If you take a look at `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` you will see exactly how it was done.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a different MOTD per user. Just add in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
Match User root
    Banner /etc/rootbanner
```

Also, you can disable root login in that same file, just changing

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

To:

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Best regards!